# Convert raw string to a format based on regex in awk

Tags: regex, unix, awk

How do i convert

```
D84011201426    123450098741003**2014-11-26-01.55.23.000000**
```

to

```
26/11/2014 01.55.23.000000
```

using awk

I have tried multiple options but I am not able to extract the correct date from the string.

```
 echo 'D84011201426    1234500987410032014-11-26-01.55.23.000000'|awk '/^D.([0-9])/ { print $1 }'
```

I want to assign variable names to date , month , year and timestamp and then orint like : $1 $2 $3 $4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
$ awk -F'(**|-)' '{print $4"/"$3"/"$2, $5}'
```

If the `**` are a typo in your sample input :

```
$  echo 'D84011201426    1234500987410032014-11-26-01.55.23.000000' |
    awk -F'([0-9]{15}|-)' '{print $4"/"$3"/"$2, $5}'
```

Output:

```
26/11/2014 01.55.23.000000
```

Comment: Thanks sputnick for bringing me close, it is giving the output as :
01.55.23.000000/26/11 , can you please guide me how do I extract year as well.. I am new to regex and struggling on this .

Comment: My code works as expected with your example containing `**`. Maybe it's a typo ??? Or an attempt to put a substring in bold ?

Comment: `$ echo 'D84011201426    1234500987410032014-11-26-01.55.23.000000' | awk -F'([0-9]{15}|-)' '{print $4"/"$3"/"$2, $5}'



01.55.23.000000/26/11`

Comment: $5 seems to be coming as blank

Comment: Not for me. Maybe you can try others positions by yourself ?!

Answer (score 1):

This is really better suited to sed than awk since it's a simple subsitution on a single line:

```
$ echo 'D84011201426    1234500987410032014-11-26-01.55.23.000000' |
    sed -r 's#.*(....)-(..)-(..)-#\3/\2/\1 #'
26/11/2014 01.55.23.000000
```

but here's the equivalent in GNU awk if it's useful:

```
$ echo 'D84011201426    1234500987410032014-11-26-01.55.23.000000' |
    awk '{print gensub(/.*(....)-(..)-(..)-/,"\\3/\\2/\\1 ","")}'
26/11/2014 01.55.23.000000
```

Comment: Thanks Ed , I will implement this one.